# Is there a formula for omitted variable bias for multiple variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, bias

Based on this video, the omitted variable formula for two independent variables are:

[image]

I am wondering how do you modify the formula if you have more than two independent variables? Let's say keeping X2, X3, X4 constant, how do you determine the effect of X5 on X2, X3, X4?

Comment: You need some assumptions here. I assume you mean that X2, X3 and X4 are in your model, whereas X5 is omitted AND X5 is correlated with X2, X3 and X4? Since if it's not correlated it will not be biased.